# wait() does not catch notify(); causes weird deadlock behavior

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, deadlock, monitor

I'm modelling a train system with eight stations with threads and monitors. The system is modeled as follows, using a circular linked list:

```
   S2-S3-S4
  /        \
 S1        S5
 >\        /
   S8-S7-S6
```

All elements of the linked list are of the class `Segment`. There are two types of `Segment`s, `FreeSegment`s and `Station`s.

Trains run concurrently on the system as threads traversing the linked list. The code of the train thread is as follows:

```
public void runWithMonitors(boolean showMsgs) {
    // This is the entry monitor
    synchronized (entryPoint) {
        try {
            // Wait until the next segment is clear
            // This loop guards against spurious wakeups as recommended
            // by the official Java documentation
            while (entryPoint.isOccupied()) {
                entryPoint.wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            print("Services interrupted.", showMsgs);
        }
    }

    // Run this code indefinitely
    while (true) {
        // This is the current segment monitor
        // Only one train can ever occupy this segment
        // Take note of the current segment
        Segment currSegmentMonitor = currSegment;

        synchronized (currSegmentMonitor) {
            // Take this spot
            currSegment.setIsOccupied(true);
            currSegment.setTrainInside(this);

            // If this segment is a station, load and unload passengers
            if (currSegmentMonitor instanceof Station) {
                // Open doors and allow passengers to get off and on
                alightPassengers(showMsgs);
                loadPassengers(showMsgs);
            }

            // Notify this train's observer that its position has changed
            trainObserver.update(dispatcher, showMsgs);

            // Is it okay to proceed?
            try {
                // Wait until the next segment is clear
                // This loop guards against spurious wakeups as recommended
                // by the official Java documentation
                while (nextSegment.isOccupied()) {
                    currSegmentMonitor.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                print("Services interrupted.", showMsgs);
            }

            // Leave this spot
            currSegment.setIsOccupied(false);
            currSegment.setTrainInside(null);

            // If ready, then proceed
            proceed();

            // Then tell others we're done occupying that spot
            currSegmentMonitor.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

**proceed() implementation**

```
// Move forward
private void proceed() {
    // We've just moved to the next segment
    currSegment = nextSegment;
    nextSegment = currSegment.getNextSegment();
}
```

Before a train can enter the system, it must wait for the entry segment to be clear. The entry segment is denoted by the `>` character before the first station (S1).

Once inside the loop, any train at a segment must *wait* for the next segment to be clear before it proceeds. This is implemented by `wait()`ing on the current segment until another train thread `notify()`s it.

However, upon testing, the `wait()`s don't honor the `notify()`s *at all*, causing a train to wait for no reason, deadlocking the system.

I'm testing the system with two or more threads.

**Additional observations**

I tried to replace the `try` block with the `wait()` with the code:

```
while (nextSegment.isOccupied());
```

I assumed that removing the `wait()` would work, but it still results in deadlocks for some reason.

The interesting part, though, is that when placing a debug print statement inside the busy wait, like so:

```
while (nextSegment.isOccupied()) {
    System.out.println("Next segment: " +   nextSegment.isOccupied());
}
```

It works normally.

Comment: I suggest that you enter a short sleep in the loop after the update call.

Comment: `while (nextSegment.isOccupied()) {
                    currSegmentMonitor.wait();
                }` should be `while (nextSegment.isOccupied()) {
                    nextSegment.wait();
                }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use monitors. The problem with monitors is that if no threads are waiting, the `notify()` call is ignored.

Use [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) instead, where the "permit" represents the permission to enter the segment, i.e. that the segment is "free".

When a train wants to enter a segment, it calls [`acquire()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire--), and when it leaves a segment, it calls [`release()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#release--). All the segments are initialized with 1 permit, i.e. all segments are initially "empty".

You can even use the [`availablePermits()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) to determine if the segment is currently "occupied".

---

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to use `Semaphore`, here's what wrong with your code:

Your code is "locking" the current segment, so access to the segment is controlled, however the following code violates that:

```
while (nextSegment.isOccupied()) {
    currSegmentMonitor.wait();
}
```

Here the code accesses the `nextSegment` without having a lock on that segment, i.e. without synchronizing on the segment.

In addition to that, the code is waiting on the wrong monitor, because it is waiting on the current monitor, even though it should be waiting on the *next* monitor.

Change code to this, to fix it:

```
synchronized (nextSegment) {
    while (nextSegment.isOccupied()) {
        nextSegment.wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if `notify` is missed, as long as it's checking a condition.

Comment: Thank you. I've realized that it's actually more helpful to think of, say, `a.wait()` as **wait *on* `a` for a notification** rather than **`a` *will* wait for a notification**.